# rounding errors in threejs chrome vs firefox

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a plane in a three JS scene with a certain position and rotation.
I am sending a raycast towards this plane, and then I am in essence projecting an object towards it. It has worked great until I noticed that the projection gets turned upside down in firefox, but not in chromium.

This causes quite a lot of problems for me, and it seems like it boils down to a rounding error when the mesh is updating the matrix.

Here is an example that highlights the issue

```js
const test = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
test.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(-0.0800582263098657,0,-0.003907569688712309))
test.rotation.copy(new THREE.Euler(-1.5707963267948966,0,0, "XYZ"))
test.updateMatrix()
const asString = `[${test.matrix.elements.join(",")}]`
const chromeString = "[1,0,0,0,0,2.220446049250313e-16,-1,0,0,1,2.220446049250313e-16,0,-0.0800582263098657,0,-0.003907569688712309,1]"
console.log(`
${asString}
${chromeString}
${asString === chromeString ? "equal" : "not equal"}
`)
```

as you might assume, this prints `equal` for chromium, but not firefox.
The diff that I am seeing is for example that the fifth element changes sign on firefox... since it is `e-16` it is not a large difference, but the sign change causes the projection to turn upside down.

I have tried setting the matrix manually (turning of the matrixAutoUpdate) to the chrome result, and that fixes the issue for firefox, so I am quite certain that it boils down to this calculation.

I guess the question is:
Can I change anything to make the calculations the same? I am OK with loosing some precision if I gain consistency across browsers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in a pretty hacky and non-optimal way

```
function setMatrixPrecisionOnMesh(mesh: THREE.Object3D) {
    const update = mesh.updateMatrix;
    mesh.updateMatrix = function updateMatrix() {
        const precision = 10000000
        const round = (num) => Math.round(num * precision) / precision;
        this.position.setX(round(this.position.x));
        this.position.setY(round(this.position.y));
        this.position.setZ(round(this.position.z));
        this.rotation.set(
            round(this.rotation.x),
            round(this.rotation.y),
            round(this.rotation.z),
            this.rotation.order
        )
        update.call(this, {});
    }
}
```

calling that method with my mesh will cause the values to round to a level where both V8 and SpiderMonkey handles it the same way.
So it "works", but might be a better solution out there somewhere